# What is the proper way to connect this metal pipe to the pvc pipe coming out of it?

Tags: bathroom, drain, pvc

Currently trying to fix my drain set up in bathroom sink. It’s not leaking anywhere else except where these two pipes join and only when there’s a lot of water coming through (such as full sink drain or both hot and cold water on) .. I am able to unscrew the nut and there is no gasket or anything, only pvc shoved into thay pipe. What would be the correct repair here?

[image]

Comment: First what is that black line on the pipe?  It looks like maybe a crack or hair.  It also looks like water drops on the pipe, water usually does not flow up.  There should be a rubber like ring under that nut to seal to the plastic pipe.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified I took care of the pvc connection leak. I think that’s just the lighting of the water on the pvc. It’s not leaking there anymore, just at the bottom where pvc goes into metal

Comment: The plastic is almost certainly polypropylene for this fitting.

Comment: see https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/238932/18078

Answer (score 4):

Your plastic-to-metal connection is a compression connection. It uses 3 parts:

- The female end (metal in your case), with threading on the ***outside***
- The "compression nut" which slides over the male end (plastic in your case) and then threads on to the threaded female end.
- A flexible rubber "compression washer" with an angled edge (not flat or round) that slides up onto the male end ***after*** you slide the nut on. You are missing this. The wider face of the washer faces the nut, with the narrower "cone" end facing the threaded female end.

To make a watertight seal, the washer is compressed by screwing the nut onto the threads, perhaps hand tight plus a half turn or so. With the rubber washer now pressed against the female end by the nut, it bulges out against both the outside of the inner male pipe and the inside end of the outer female pipe, making a good seal.

Sample exploded view of a proper connection:

[image]

I'd suggest buying a kit with both a red rubber compression washer (a "reducing washer" most likely) and a new plastic nut to replace the metal nut on your pipe. An easily-replaced plastic nut will likely fail first if you tighten it too hard without damaging the hard-to-change metal pipe/threads.

Sample kit with two different sizes of washers:

[image]

It looks like your metal pipe is perhaps a size larger than the plastic pipe. The wider washer shown is a "reducing" washer for such a situation. Just measure the ***outer diameter*** of your plastic pipe and make sure the washer's inside diameter matches that. Make sure the washer's outer diameter matches the metal pipe, as it should fit snugly against/in the face of the female pipe as seen in the exploded view.

Probably easiest to bring the metal nut (and plastic pipe?) along to the store to make sure you get parts that fit size- and threading-wise.

Comment: Where I live, these are called "slip-joints", "slip-joint washers/nuts", etc., never "compression joints", which are an entirely different thing.

Comment: seems fairly similar to me, both use a nut and a gland

Comment: @kreemoweet slip joint might indeed be more common (and more specific). As you note "compression" covers a range of plastic and metal connections that work in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The part that I have coloured blue unscrews like a bottle cap under it is a rubber ring washer that seals the two pipes together.